# node ios socket.io SSL works with xcode debug but does not with ipa install

Tags: ios, xcode, node.js, ssl, socket.io

Having node https setup

```
const server = require('https').createServer(
{
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/some.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/some.crt')
}, handler);
```

iOS app performs good with xcode debug, but misses connectivity when app distributed via .ipa file.

Comment: Do you have any solution ?

Comment: I do not know why debug-version is working. It should not neither in debug neighter in release(ipa). In my case it was a broken https setup (missed intermediate.crt). Try to check you SSL setup, including completeness of setup, validity of certificates, clock settings on both server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Node https setup must include intermediate CA certificate (provided by Certificate Authority):

```
const server = require('https').createServer(
{
    // this line is required.
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/intermediate.crt'),

    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/some.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/some.crt')
}, handler);
```